# How to use TinyMCE functions on text without actually selecting that text?

Tags: jquery, tinymce, caret

I have various `<div>`s  on my page, which, when clicked, convert into TinyMCE editor sections. So the user can just double click on the div and then edit the text within it using TinyMCE.

My question is - is it possible to run the TinyMCE functions on a `<div>` without actually having the text inside selected? What I mean is, I want to implement the following use case:

1. User clicks on a `<div>`.
2. `<div>` activates a TinyMCE session on itself.
3. User can now use the buttons on the TinyMCE toolbar to edit all the text in the div, without having to actually select the text manually using the cursor. Otherwise the usual case is that the user has to select some of the text, and only this selected text will be edited by the TinyMCE tools.

How can this be implemented, and how easy is it?

### Edit

Clarification: I do not mean only that all text should automatically be selected by TinyMCE editor for changes, but I mean that without selecting at all, can it be formatted? My objective is to allow users to be able to edit only the *formatting* of a `<div>` using TinyMCE, but not to be able to change the text itself. I actually don't want the user to be able to select any text, just click on the `<div>`, which should automatically allow the contained text to be *formatted* by TinyMCE, without its text actually being changed. But the textarea should not be "selectable" for the user, if you know what I mean. It can select itself if needed (as per @Thariama's solution below), but just not by the user. Is this possible? Sort of like enabling just the TinyMCE toolbar buttons but disabling the text editing capabilities. As far as I've understood, I can't use the `readonly` configuration of TinyMCE it also disables the toolbar with all the formatting options (like text highlight, bold, italics etc).

Comment: So in effect you want all the text contained in the editor to be selected when the editor is loaded, right?

Comment: right, but without the editor area being actually "editable" by the user. What I mean is, a div already exists with some text in it, and I want the user to be able to edit its style without changing the text.

Comment: I've edited my question to add the clarification.

Comment: I know this is not really what you wanted, but I did it just for fun... http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/U9Hw2/1/ Double clicking editable element will reveal styling options.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wish I could do something like that, unfortunately I need a lot more complex editing and formatting including plugins and custom-made plugins that I've made in TinyMCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for me was to use a combination of @Thariama's setup code:

```
tinyMCE.init({ ....
    setup : function(ed) {  
    ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt) {

        ed.getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);

        var range = ed.selection.dom.createRng();

        range.setStartBefore(ed.getBody().firstChild);
        range.setEndAfter(ed.getBody().lastChild);
        ed.selection.setRng(range);
    });
}
});
```

With a way to disable keypresses in the textarea, i.e. if my textarea has an ID of `TAID`, then I added this code:

`$('#TAID_ifr').contents().find('html').bind('keypress', function(e){return false;});`

Answer (score 2):

It is not a big problem to select all editor content after tinymce got initialized.This can be done easily using the setup configuration parameter

```
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(ed) {
        ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt) {

            ed.getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);

            var range = ed.selection.dom.createRng();

            range.setStartBefore(ed.getBody().firstChild);
            range.setEndAfter(ed.getBody().lastChild);
            ed.selection.setRng(range);
        });
   }
});
```

[Here](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/I3caab/1) is a tinymce fiddle for this.

Update:

What you are looking for is something like `$(ed.getBody()).attr('contenteditable','false');`
This way a user won't be able to select or even edit the editor content, but the tinymce buttons are still usable (with all consequences).
You could create an own toolbar element with the desired functionality.

Comment: Thanks for this! It does make my problem easier, however this is not entirely what I meant - I've edited my question to add a clarification.

Comment: Where do I use this code? I tried it inside the onInit.add function but I got an error, I tried it outside (while still within the setup function) but also got an error, this time that `getDoc()` is undefined. Do you mind showing where you would place that line in your code?

Comment: Thanks! I tried it as you said it. However, while text is indeed un-editable, and the toolbar buttons are indeed still visible, the problem is they don't work any more. So although the text is selected automatically, I cannot change its color or size. I do want the buttons to still operate on the selected text, but doing so while contenteditable is false gives an error that `q is null`. Can this be worked around by maybe leaving contenteditable true but trapping and keypress events in the iframe and making them return false?

Comment: in that case you will need to place a transparent div over the editor content in order to have all buttons still working

Comment: Done! I just used this code, given that the textarea within the editor is "TAID":
`$('#TAID_ifr').contents().find('html').bind('keypress', function(e){return false;});`. So content is editable using buttons but the user can't actually play with the text.

Comment: Yes, the issue with the transparent div was that I already had too many events and plugins tied to the div that consisted of the textarea, if I put a div on top, a lot of other changes would need to be made. The drawback of this though, is that the caret still appears.

Comment: Any idea how can the caret be captured in this case? Because it isn't really a textarea during editing, as far as I know, it's `<p>` within an iframe. So I'm assuming that TinyMCE is actually creating a sort of pseudo-caret effect without using a real caret, in which case I can just change the pseud-caret's color to transparent.

Comment: afaik, it is a real (browser) caret

Comment: is it possible for the text selection part to be cross-browser/version/platform compatible? I've just asked a follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902774/cross-browser-compatible-select-all-tinymce-text-after-initilization