# jQuery capture enter key and prevent default

Tags: jquery, tinymce, keypress, enter, preventdefault

Referring to the answer here:
[How to use TinyMCE functions on text without actually selecting that text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13951093/how-to-use-tinymce-functions-on-text-without-actually-selecting-that-text)

I've realized that

```
$('#TAID_ifr').contents().find('html').bind('keypress', function(e){return false;});
```

doesn't work for the enter key. When a user hits "enter", a newline is formed. But for all other keys, the code works as expected, i.e. nothing happens. Does enter require some special treatment? I added the code below but it  didn't make a difference:

```
            var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
                if (code == 13) e.preventDefault();
```

What's wrong? I don't want a new line to be inserted when a user hits "enter", I want nothing to happen.

### Edit

Does this not work because the `enter` key is pressed inside an iframe?

Comment: What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: and by the way `$('#TAID_ifr')` is it `textarea` or `iframe`?

Comment: it's an iframe. it's the way TinyMCE works - we end up editing an iframe which is dressed up for us like a textarea. I'm using jQuery 1.8

Comment: `var code = e.keyCode || e.which;` Have you tried only using only one of these like `var code = e.which;`.

Comment: Yes, no difference. Anyway I do want to keep that option for other browsers.

Comment: @Thariama do you have any idea if this is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Tinymce uses its own event management.
There is a [tinymce event](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3aevent.tinymce.Editor.onKeyDown) called `onKeyDown`. Using the [setup configuration parameter](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3asetup) you may use this event:

```
// Adds an observer to the onKeyDown event using tinyMCE.init
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onKeyDown.add(function(ed, event) {

          if (event.keyCode == 13)  {
              event.preventDefault();
              event.stopPropagation();
              return false;
          }
      });
   }
});
```

Be aware that several statements are used here to stop the propagation of code due to the fact that the implementation in different browsers differs.

Comment: you saved the day again! :) I've been at this for the past two days, thank you!

Comment: glad to have been able to help

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
$('#TAID_ifr').keypress(function(event){

    if (event.keyCode == 10 || event.keyCode == 13)  {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In TinyMce 4.x, use the following snippet, as documented [here](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/events/):

```
// Adds an observer to the onKeyDown event using tinyMCE.init
tinymce.init({
   ...
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.on('KeyDown', function(event) {
          if (event.keyCode == 13)  {
              event.preventDefault();
              event.stopPropagation();
              return false;
          }
      });
   }
});
```